# Should you seasonally adjust time series if hypothesis testing shows there to be no identifiable seasonality?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, seasonality

I have run tests for stable seasonality and moving seasonality.

The tests are unable to find presence of seasonality in the time series I am working with.

I am wondering if I can still seasonally adjust the time series? What would be the potential issue in seasonally adjusting a time series if there is no identifiable seasonal component?

Comment: Try it and look to see how it may distort results.  Decide which autocorrelation and partial autocorrelation set is more trustworthy.  I expect you'll find the distortion to be nontrivial.

Comment: Just because the seasonality isn't statistically significant doesn't mean it won't affect other parameters or estimates. In fact, it will affect them. The question is how much and in what ways?